# How to turn a pivoted forecast with columns into a formulaic row-based output?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, split, flatten, google-query-language

Wondering the best way to do this in Sheets - I have a forecast with strings in column A, and 10 columns worth of forecasted data. So column A would have the store name, columns B-K would have the forecasted sales volume.

I need to bring this down to row level output for each store one after the other (so that column A has 10 rows worth of data with just 3 columns - store name, week of forecast, forecasted sales volume, then the next store, then the next, etc)...the week of forecast is obviously currently in the first row for B-K.

How would I build a formula to do this in a separate tab? I'd want to do one formula in A1 that can pull in store 1's 10 rows, then store 2's 10 rows, and on and on...this CAN'T be done by putting in a formula in A1, then A11, and so on (otherwise I'd already be done).

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lySVQSCz7Nt3fea0rDYmqNmXsTqhOibiYS6lgU5UajU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A7&"×"&B1:1&"×"&B2:7), "×"), "where Col2 is not null"))
```

[image]